# How do I deploy Nuxt 3 app on IIS server?

Tags: iis, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm trying to build and host Nuxt 3 app(SSR not static) on IIS server but couldn't find a way so far

Here are the steps I tried:

1. Project Preparation:
   npx nuxi init 
   cd 
   yarn run build
2. then I follow the steps suggested on [nuxt official page](https://nuxt.com/deploy/iis) and [nitro](https://nitro.unjs.io/deploy/providers/iis#using-iis-handler)
3. Tried both methods suggested by links above but still couldn't get it right after pointing my site to this .output folder mentioned

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/running-nuxt-3-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: @LexLi where should i put this web.config?  there are two folders: "public" and "server" inside .output folder, I tried put web.config inside .output folder but getting error 403

Comment: That article assumes you create the site on IIS and point to the folder that contains your `package.json` file.

Comment: This link should help you: [https://nuxt.com/deploy/iis](https://nuxt.com/deploy/iis).